# How to solve type mismatch error from double to int in Java

Tags: java, colors

In my class we are doing some color conversions. I have been able to figure out simple color conversions like red, blue, green, purple, and yellow but I have been unable to figure out how to make a color like orange or brown. I tried multiplying by a decimal, such as g*0.6 but then I end up with a type mismatch (double instead of int).

```
public void toYellow() {
    //convert to yellow
    for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++){
            int p = img.getRGB(x,y);
            int a = (p>>24)&0xff;
            int r = (p>>16)&0xff;
            int g = (p>>8)&0xff;
            int b = p&0xff;
            //set blue to zero
            p = (a<<24) | (r<<16) | (g<<8) | 0;
            
            img.setRGB(x, y, p);
            setColor("Yellow");
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: use `(int)(g*0.6)` to cast the double back to an int

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked perfectly :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(int)(g*0.6)` to cast the double back to an int